# How to convert a string to float (without adding lines)

Tags: python, string, int, calculator

I am trying to program a python calculator in the least lines possible, I have so far (in theory) gotten it down to 10. The only problem is I cannot seem to work out how to change two of the strings to floats, without adding more lines.

```
x = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ")
a, b, c = x.split()
if b == "-":
    print (a-c)
elif b == "+":
    print (a+c)
elif b == "*":
    print (a*c)
elif b == "/":
    print (a/b)
```

I know that I will have to do *float()* somewhere, I just haven't managed to find where.

Edit:  *I am trying to get it as low as I can as I challenge, in this  instance I don't care if it's messy. Also I know not to make your code too 'overlapping' and confusing.

Comment: Why are you so worried about the extra line?

Comment: @dunes I'm challenging a friend, we both managed to get it down to 14 an I've been trying to get it as low as possible. I have come to the conclusion that 10 is minimum.

Comment: In that case you can use `a, b, c = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.   ").split()` to reduce it one line further.

Comment: I normally just convert either my numerator to a float during division.  print (float(a)/b) ... this coerces the entire expression to evaluate into a float while also making it clear to the reader that my intention is to deal with real rather than integer response.

Comment: @JimDennis except in this case the operands are strings, not ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ")
a, b, c = x.split()
if b == "-":
    print float(a)-float(c)
elif b == "+":
    print float(a)+float(c)
elif b == "*":
    print float(a)*float(c)
elif b == "/":
    print float(a)/float(c) # replaced b to c
```

Comment: I get the error:     TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @Joshua how about now ?

Comment: @Joshua Isn't it more logic to do **1** float conversion instead of in many places? even tho it only occurs once because of `if` and `elif` but it makes more sense?

Answer (score 4):

If you want short, then the following is short (though you could merge lines 2 and 3 together). However, readable it is not.

```
from operator import add, sub, truediv, mul
ops = {"+": add, "-": sub, "/": truediv, "*": mul}
x, op, y = [float(string) if i % 2 == 0 else string for i, string in enumerate(raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ").split())]
print(ops[op](x, y))
```

The lesson from all this is that whilst terseness is good -- shorter code is in general quicker and easier to read -- if defeats the point of being terse if the code is overly complex.

**For the sadistic (the above as a one liner):**

```
(lambda x, op, y, operator=__import__("operator"), opnames={"+": "add", "-": "sub", "/": "truediv", "*": "mul"}: getattr(operator, opnames[op])(x, y))(*[float(s) if i % 2 == 0 else s for i, s in enumerate(raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ").split())])
```

**For those who know how to use** `ast.literal_eval`**:**

```
__import__("ast").literal_eval(raw_input("Enter calc instructions.\n"))
```

**For those who don't mind their calculators having security flaws...**

```
input("Enter calc instructions.\n")
```

Comment: Bro, shorter? `ast.literal_eval(input("Enter calc instructions.\n"))` is enough(`literal_eval` is safe and is not like `eval`). :)

Comment: Hmm... It come up with   " AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' "

Comment: @BhargavRao Fo sho. Could be even shorter if you used `__import__` to get `ast` rather than an in import statement. I was just trying to stress that short code isn't some ideal to strive towards regardless of consequence.

Comment: @Joshua I was working with python 3 where raw_input is named input. Changed the code to work on python 2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line

```
a,c = float(a),float(c)
```

or

```
a,c = map(float,(a,c))
```

before

```
if b == "-":
```

Without a extra line

- Change all the `print` statements to `print (float(a)+float(c))` and so on

**OR**

- Change `split` statement to `a,b,c = float(s.split()[0]),s.split()[1],float(s.split()[2])`

Note, it is better to have an additional line, than to compress everything

Comment: Can I somehow do this without adding an extra line?

Comment: Why does the split statement have to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ")
a, b, c = x.split(); a=float(a); c=float(c)
if b == "-":
    print(a-c)
elif b == "+":
    print(a+c)
elif b == "*":
    print(a*c)
elif b == "/":
    print(a/b)
```

Doesn't add a additional line, as per requested.
But then again, you probably should worry less about 1 additional line of code :)

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float.  An yeah, I realise now that tiny code is often unbearable.

Comment: @Joshua my bad, `c=float(c)`, can't convert `b` which is `+` to a float. Corrected and also switch to Python3.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: your question is misguided, you can get the entire code down to 2 lines. Maybe even less, you should have posted this on the [code golf site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

```
a, b, c = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ").split()
print {'*': float.__mul__, '/': float.__div__, '+': float.__add__, '-': float.__sub__}[b](float(a), float(c))
```

---

Original answer:

Here's a one-liner that gives a float if the number matches a floating point pattern, otherwise keeps the string.

```
a, b, c = [float(y) if re.match('[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*', y) else y for y in x.split()]
```

Unfortunately I couldn't think of an easy way to allow a number without a leading digit, since it needed to consider a plain `-` as a string.

Comment: Yay! A one-liner ... But wait! Where is `import re`?

Comment: Why are you using the `__rop__` versions of the operators? In the case of non-commutative operations it produces the wrong answer (eg. `1 / 2` comes out as `2.0` rather `0.5`).

Comment: @Dunes I didn't have the documentation that told me the difference. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

One liner that works with any amount of decimal numbers and negative numbers

For example - `x = "2.7+72/2 * 100"` will output `[2.7, '+', 72.0, '/', '2 ', '*', 100.0]`

However, since your code only works with 3 values, you'd have to edit it to make use of it (and if you fancy trying, just remove the `[:3]` from the end of the line)

```
x = raw_input("Enter calc instructions.  ")

a, b, c = [float(i) if all(j.strip().isdigit() or j[1:].strip().isdigit() for j in i.split(".")) else i for i in "".join([x[i] if x[i] not in ["-","+","*","/"] else ("|{}|".format(x[i]) if (":"+x)[i-1] in ["-","+","*","/"] else x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]).split("|")][:3]

if b == "-":
    print (a-c)
elif b == "+":
    print (a+c)
elif b == "*":
    print (a*c)
elif b == "/":
    print (a/b)
```

Comment: Fixed, the line is getting a bit long now though haha

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want another line and you want to modify your code you can try this:

```
x = input("Enter calc instructions.  ")
a, b, c = x.split()
if b == "-":
    print (float(a)-float(c))
elif b == "+":
    print (float(a)+float(c))
elif b == "*":
    print (float(a)*float(c))
elif b == "/":
    print (float(a)/float(c))
```

It works in Python 3.4.